# How can i send my data in popup.html?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension and i am trying to send the data that is coming in an array and wanna show it to my popup html but i am unable to do it i tried going by the links but i dont know why its not working for me.
here are my codes please check where is the fault:-

popup html:-

```
<div class="as-center button-info display-none div_three_main">
      <div class="img_area">
        <img src="images/right.png" alt="extension_logo" >
      </div>
      <p class="pop-up_text-heading">Success!</p>
      <p class="pop-up_text"> {count} members found. </p>
      <button class="input-btn scrap-button">Download CSV</button>
    </div>
```

content.js:-

```
var main = [];
var count = main.length;

chrome.tabs.sendMessage({ action: "count", count : 'count'});
```

background.js:-

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message["action"] == "new") {        
         chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
                if (tabs.length > 0) {
                    var msg = {action:'new',count:count};
                     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            });

    }
  });
```

popup.js:-

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, send Response) {

    if(request.action === 'new')
    {
        alert('here',request.count);
    }  
});
```

please give me a answer to send the total elements from main array and to display it in my popup.html

Comment: Content script should use chrome.runtime.sendMessage, no need for the background page at all. Also you're not sending the actual `count`, you're sending a string `'count'`.

Comment: you are sending the string 'count' instead of variable `count` here `chrome.tabs.sendMessage({ action: "count", count : 'count'});`

Comment: can you give mee a  answer how to do it i tried by doing everuthing but i am unable to do it